# BOR vs BRO predicate testing

Tags: testing, prolog

So right now I'm studying BOR-CSET constraint set and BRO constraint set using ASTs. I read the book and looked online but I still don't really understand the difference between them, they seem the same to me, can anyone explain more clearly whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some predicate that is made up of relational operators:

- > Greater than
- < Less than
- = Equal to

And also made up of Boolean operators:

- AND
- OR
- NOT

And you would like to perform testing to see if the predicate produces the correct result. Rather than putting every possible combination of numbers and true/false inputs into the predicate and checking each answer (which might be an infinite number of inputs) you can instead develop a testing set of inputs that will be guaranteed to detect any faults in your predicate. If the test inputs don't show up any problems then you can know for sure that your predicate works as expected.

A **BOR** set of tests will detect if you have made some mistake by using the wrong Boolean operator (for example you put in an OR when you really needed an AND). A **BRO** set will detect when you have used the wrong Boolean operator and also when you have used the wrong relational operator (for example you used a greater than sign somewhere where you really needed a less than sign).

Comment: great! thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Are there more than one possible constraint sets generated by BRO-CSET? I solved a question that our instructor put an answer to but our solutions differ, my constraint set is different because I chose different operators when doing the approach